# How do I bind an ImageSource to a specific element's property in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, binding, observablecollection

I would really like to know how I can bind an ImageSource to a specific element's property in an ObservableCollection... Right now I have this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainPage"
             x:Name = "Main"
             Padding="5,20,5,5"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=Main }">
        <Grid 
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Source="{Binding _hand[0].ResourceId , Converter={StaticResource 
                StringToSourceConverter}}"
                >
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Source="{Binding _hand[1].ResourceId , Converter={StaticResource 
                StringToSourceConverter}}"
                >
            </ImageButton>
          
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Source="{Binding _hand[2].ResourceId , Converter={StaticResource 
                StringToSourceConverter}}"
                >
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                 Source="{Binding _hand[3].ResourceId , Converter={StaticResource 
                StringToSourceConverter}}"
                >
            </ImageButton>
        </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I would like to bind the ImageSource to the following ObservableCollection of Cards...

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Card> _hand;
 
        public MainPage()
        {
            Init();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       
       
        private void Init()
        {

            _hand = new ObservableCollection<Card>()
            {
                new Card("image1.jpg"),
                new Card("image2.jpg"),
                new Card("image3.jpg"),
                new Card("image4.jpg")

            };
        }
    }
```

My Card class looks something like this:

```
public Card ( string resourceId)
        {
            ResourceId = resourceId;
        }

        public string ResourceId { get; set; }
```

The Converter used :

```
public class ToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string ResourceId = value.ToString(); 
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResourceId))
                return null;
            return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        
        
    }
```

My question now is how do I make this code work? Also I have methods that switch elements in the collection. Where do I implement PropertyChangedEvent? Thank you guys a lot :)

Comment: 1) why use Databinding, if your `ObservableCollection` _hand lives in the codebehind - which is the same class as the view - anyway and not in a separate ViewModel class? 2) you need to implement the `INotifypropertyChanged` Interface in your `Card` class and fire the notification event in the setter of the `ResourceId` property. ObservableCollection itself will only update if the collection is changed (ie elements added/deleted etc), but not if the elements themselves are changed.

Comment: @RolandDeschain thanks alot. Alright... But what about the Binding itself? I do not think this is the proper way... My way expects a property. It should receive _cards[someIndex].ResourceId....

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `_hand` is neither of these

Comment: @RolandDeschain And I think it doesn't make sense to implement the fire the notification event up when the ResourceId changes. I don't  change the resourceId it actually stays the same. I arrange the Cards different...

Comment: @Jason so the problem is solved as soon as I make it public ?

Comment: I have no idea if that will solve **all** of your problems - you will have to try it and see

Comment: @Jason  Source="{Binding _hand[0].ResourceId, Converter={StaticResource StringToSourceConverter}}"

Comment: @LucaHafer as Jason said bound objects have to be public propertiers (with getter/setters). The Inotifypropertychanged event basically tells the GUI object, that the bound object has changed. Even if you don't change them later, you have to set them at some point (at startup of the program). However, if you don't plan to change them, question is, why net set the image paths directly without databinding at all?

Comment: @Jason it gives me the error that it is searching for a property... I made the Collection public

Comment: did you also make it a property?

Comment: @RolandDeschain I thought it would be more elegant... Could you be a bit more specific, please? Maybe with some example code?

Comment: @Jason no i didn't xD now it works

Comment: @Jason I think you solved my problems

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (wasn't at my pc), but yeah, you can set the path to your image directly in the xaml file. IIRC you need to include the corresponding image into the project in Visual Studio, but in general with a bit of google-fu this shouldn't be too difficult. Doing the whole thing via databinding makes only sense (at least in my humble opinion), if you design your whole application around the MVVM pattern. :)